# Problema para trabajar con Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Estoy intentando trabajar con Django y no he podido. No puedo acceder a Django desde el cmd.
Hay que configurar algo en el path para trabajar con Django? 
-- C:\Django-1.10.8\django\bin--

Tengo el path correcto con Python, y agregue a Django a las variables de entorno. 
-- C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\C:\Django-1.10.8\django\bin --

Si alguien puede decirme algo, seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que no reconoce `django-admin`?¿Cómo has instalado Django?¿Has usado `pip` para ello?

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a adelantar un poco con esta respuesta xq realmente no queda del todo claro tu pregunta, pero me parece q este puede ser tu problema.

Partiendo de que dices que tienes ya Python agregado al path.

Respondiendo a *Hay que configurar algo en el path para trabajar con Django?*

1. El path a la carpeta q contiene el ejecutable de Python
2. El path a la carpeta *Scripts* que debe estar al mismo nivel de el ejecutable de python.

La carpeta de Django no.

Luego de esto puedes instalar Django via *Pip* o directamente ejecutando el *setup.py*

Ex 1 - sin PIP: `python <path_to_django_folder>\setup.py install`

Ex 2 - con PIP: `pip install django` o `pip install <path_to_django_folder>\django.tar.gz`

Luego puedes usar crear un projecto de la siguiente forma:

```
python django-admin.py startproject <path_for_project>
```

o

```
django-admin startproject <path_for_project>
```

Espero q te resuelva.
PD: deberias estudiar como usa entornos virtuales para que puedas usar los paquetes necesarios para cada proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que no le colocaste punto y coma entre cada variable del path:

**Así lo tienes vos:**

```
C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\C:\Django-1.10.8\django\bin
```

**Debería ser así:**

```
C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Django-1.10.8\django\bin
```